# List data from database using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to list data using angular js.Datas it coming but what can ı write there "data in markers "?

**Here my controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var list = db.kayitlar.ToList();
        string markers = "[";
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            markers += "{";
            markers += item.name;
            markers += item.surname;
            markers += item.money;
            markers += item.country;
            markers += "},";
        }
        markers += "];";
        ViewBag.Markers = markers;

        return View(db.kayitlar.ToList());


    }
```

**and my view**

```
@{

var markers = Html.Raw(ViewBag.Markers);
 }
```

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>surname</th>c
        <th>money</th>
        <th>country</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="data in markers">
        <td>{{data.name|uppercase}}</td>
        <td>{{data.surname|lowercase}}</td>
        <td>{{data.money|number:3}}</td>
        <td>{{data.country}}</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Here class kayitlar

```
public class kayit
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public double money { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}
```

**SQL Server table:**

[image]

How can I solve this? I am a student. Pls help me.

Comment: Can you update your post with the model class kayitlar?

Comment: Ok, let me do the demo for you.

Comment: Ok, ı am waiting. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

`AngularJS's ng-repeat` requires an array. Based in your question, your JSON must be e.g:

```
[{"name":"Danny","surname":"Surename","money":19000.0,"country":"Perú"},{"name":"Danny2","surname":"Surename2","money":14000.0,"country":"Austrlia"}]
```

**Server side:**

To render this JSON you can use `Newtonsoft.Json` (`using Newtonsoft.Json;`).

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.data = buildJson(getData());
    return View();
}
private List<kayit> getData()
{
    List<kayit> lkayit = new List<kayit>();
    kayit oKayitlar;
    oKayitlar = new kayit();
    oKayitlar.name = "Danny";
    oKayitlar.surname = "Surename";
    oKayitlar.money = 19000;
    oKayitlar.country = "Perú";
    lkayit.Add(oKayitlar);

    oKayitlar = new kayit();
    oKayitlar.name = "Danny2";
    oKayitlar.surname = "Surename2";
    oKayitlar.money = 14000;
    oKayitlar.country = "Austrlia";
    lkayit.Add(oKayitlar);
    return lkayit;
}

private string buildJson(List<kayit> list)
{
    var markers = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
    Console.Write(markers); // Prints [{"name":"Danny","surname":"Surename","money":19000.0,"country":"Perú"},{"name":"Danny2","surname":"Surename2","money":14000.0,"country":"Austrlia"}]
    return markers;
}
```

**Front-End:**

**View:**

```
<body data-ng-controller="Controller">
    <input id="hdnData" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.data" /> <!-- [{"name":"Danny","surname":"Surename","money":19000.0,"country":"Perú"},{"name":"Danny2","surname":"Surename2","money":14000.0,"country":"Austrlia"}] -->
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>surname</th>
        <th>money</th>
        <th>country</th>
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="data in markers">
        <td>{{data.name|uppercase}}</td>
        <td>{{data.surname|lowercase}}</td>
        <td>{{data.money|number:3}}</td>
        <td>{{data.country}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

**AngularJS:**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller("Controller", ["$scope", function($scope) {
      $scope.data = document.getElementById("hdnData").value;
      if ($scope.data.length > 0) {
        $scope.data = JSON.parse($scope.data);
        $scope.markers = $scope.data;
      }
    }]);
})();
```

Here is the [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LDg45V).

Hope this helps.

**Update: Getting the data from SQL Server Database with ADO.NET.**

**SQL Server Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GET_KAYIT_LIST]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT name, surename, money, country FROM kayitTable
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```

**ADO.NET:**

**blkayit.cs**

```
// BL = Business Layer
public class blkayit
{
    public List<kayit> GetkayitList()
    {
        List<kayit> lkayit = null;
        string ConnectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password = myPassword; ";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                dlkayit odlkayit = new dlkayit();
                lkayit = odlkayit.GetkayitList(con);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return lkayit;
    }
}
```

**dlkayit.cs**

```
// DL = Data Layer
public class dlkayit
{
    public List<kayit> GetkayitList(SqlConnection con)
    {
        List<kayit> lkayit = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_GET_KAYIT_LIST", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 1800;
        SqlDataReader drd = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
        if (drd != null)
        {
            lkayit = new List<kayit>();
            kayit okayit;
            while (drd.Read())
            {
                okayit = new okayit();
                okayit.name = drd.GetString(0);
                okayit.surename = drd.GetString(1);
                okayit.money = drd.GetDecimal(2);
                okayit.country = drd.GetString(3);
                lkayit.Add(okayit);
            }
            drd.Close();
        }
        return lkayit;
    }
}
```

Then in your Controller:

```
private List<kayit> getData()
{
    List<kayit> lkayit = blKayit.GetkayitList();
    return lkayit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But ı  do not write data  myself.Data must come in database on SQL.

Comment: How can ı do that?

Comment: Do you find a solution ?

Comment: Yeah, by using ADO.NET you can do that. Let me update my question.

Comment: Can you update your question with the SQL Server table that you have?

Comment: I added SQL Server table .

Comment: Thank you . I am trying.